# Rear Noise when reversing then accelerating slowly

Tags: ford, noise, mustang

A week ago, I noticed a noise coming from the rear when I reverse and press on the gas and then it slowly disappears when increasing rpms. I just had the rear main seal replaced last week. Please help. Thanks. Patricia

**UPDATE**

A rumbling or groaning noise in the rear when pressing on the gas. Like something trying to rotate and needs lubricating. I drive a 1998 ford convertible mustang.I took my car in today and had two diff mechanics test drove with me. They both say there is something like plastic loose in the trunk hitting against something. They also said that when one thing gets fixed, sometimes you hear noises from another area. I hear the noise more first thing in the morning and then goes away after a few minutes of driving.

Comment: What kind of noise?

Comment: umbling noise. As if something trying to rotate and needs lubricating.